# Why doesn't size_t complain if I keep re-declaring it?

Tags: c

How am I allowed to do the following in C?

```
char * string;
size_t string_len;
unsigned int idx;

for (idx=0; (string=src[idx]) != NULL; idx++) {
    size_t string_len = strlen(string);
    if (!(dest[idx] = malloc(string_len + 1))) {
        perror("Failed to copy string value");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    dest[idx] = string;
}
```

Shouldn't re-declaring the `size_t` on line 6 raise an error, similar to if I were to redeclare `int idx`?

Comment: The warning you *should* get is that the first `string_len` is not being used.

Comment: @user3386109 could you please clarify?

Comment: What compiler are you using? What command line did you use to compile? And what warnings did you get?

Comment: if i'm not wrong, you declare a new size_t in a different scope (curly brackets).
You can try to re-declare int idx in that scope, it should not complain also.
It will only complain if you redeclare a variable in the same scope.

Comment: `size_t` is a typedef. It doesn't have any power to 'complain', but the compller does. But there is nothing to complain about here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a variable with a given name in two different scopes, you're actually defining two separate variables with the same name, and the the one in the inner scope **masks** the one in the outer scope.  This is perfectly legal.

You will get an error however if you attempt to define two variables with the same name *in the same scope* other than file scope.  At file scope you may have multiple *declarations* but only one *definition*, i.e. only one of those may initialize the variable.